# SQL Server - break single row into two

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
ID | A  | B     | InTime                  | OutTime
10 | 19 | 18078 | 2011-09-07 16:51:56.807 | 2011-11-09 22:39:02.487
```

But I want to get data in below format

```
ID | A | B     | Time
10 | 19| 18078 | 2011-09-07 16:51:56.807
10 | 19| 18078 | 2011-11-09 22:39:02.487
```

Sorry in advance as I am a bit naive in such complex queries. I tried to search in, found various options like PIVOT, UNPIVOT, CROSS APPLY, but wan unable to found any exact solution/direction to look out in.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: the most voted answer by now doesn't work as you need. See my answer, no one used Order by and alias. I think you need it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go with something simple, like a `union all`:

```
select ID, A, B, InTime [Time] from myTable
union all
select ID, A, B, OutTime [Time] from myTable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your quick response. It worked out  :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Select ID, A, B, InTime From Table
Union All
Select ID, A, B, OutTime From Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,a,b,timein  as Time from table 
union all
select id,a,b,outtime from table 
order by id,a,b,time
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should get you what you want:

```
select id,a,b,InTime as 'Time'
from table
union all
select id,a,b,OutTime
from table
```